# How do I store an array of values and then later select from it based on user input?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a volume converter. It allows users to enter a value and select the unit to convert from and the one it will be converted into. It uses a `<select>` tag for user input selection.

The `<select>` looks like this:

```
<select name="from">
  <option value=0>--select--</option>
  <option value=1>cm3</option>
  <option value=2>m3</option>
  <option value=3>Feet3</option>
  <option value=4>Gallons(UK)</option>
  <option value=5>Gallons(US)</option>
  <option value=6>Inches3</option>
  <option value=7>Litres</option>
  <option value=8>Yards3</option>
  <option value=9>Quart(UK)</option>
</select>
```

And there is another one similar to this with the name "to".

After that I did the following in PHP:

```
$from=$_POST['from'];
$to=$_POST['to'];

function assign($from,$val)
      {
          switch ($from)
          {
              case 1:
                  $fromu="cm<sup>3</sup>";
                  $cm=1;
                  $me=0.000001;
                  $ft=0.000035315;
                  $gk=0.000219969;
                  $gs=0.000264172;
                  $in=0.061024;
                  $li=0.001;
                  $ya=0.000001308;
                  $qtk=0.000879877;
                  break;
               case 2:
                    $fromu="m<sup>3</sup>";
                    $cm=1000000;
                    $me=1;
                    $ft=35.32;
                    $gk=220;
                    $gs=264;
                    $in=61024;
                    $li=1000;
                    $ya=1.308;
                    $qtk=879.877;
                    break;
```

There are 7 more cases based on the html select "from" and each holds a value of conversion for each unit relative to the selection made.
And it ends with:

```
            echo "<br><br><table align=center>
         <tr><td><h3> ",$val," ",$fromu," equivalent is </h3></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$cm),"</u> CentiMeter<sup>3</sup></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$me),"</u> Meter<sup>3</sup></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$ft),"</u> Feet<sup>3</sup></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$gk),"</u> Gallons(UK)</td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$gs),"</u> Gallons(US)</td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$in),"</u> Inches<sup>3</sup></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$li),"</u> Litres</td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$ya),"</u> Yards<sup>3</sup></td></tr>
         <tr align=right><td><u> ",(double)($val*$qtk),"</u> Quart(UK)</td></tr></table>";
    }
    assign($from,$val);
}
```

How do I optimize this in a way that I can save all the conversion values (I'm thinking possibly in an associative array) and be able to select one based on user selection in the "to" select. (There might also be a better way to write this.)

Comment: if your code is actually working, this looks like a [good candidate](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to [move](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site#85041) to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should check out how arrays work.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Apparently I have to flag it first to get a moderator's attention for it to be moved. Might just rewrite it there instead.